# Cannot find where to execute "gradle assembleRelease" on Windows

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, release, sign

I am trying to sign my apk for release. In eclipse I could just go File->Export, type in my credentials and be good to go.

In Android Studio I read you have to execute the "gradle assembleRelease" command after setting up the gradle script.

I just can't figure out where to run this command? The Windows console does not recognize it, "where gradle" comes up empty aswell and I can only find a gradle.jar file that does not get executed in the console.

I just want to sign my apk for realease.

Answer (score 5):

The New Project wizard places a launcher script for Gradle at the root of your project; on Windows it will be gradlew.bat. If you have the signing config set up in your build files, you can run this command:

```
gradlew.bat assembleRelease
```

Alternately, you can use the **Generate Signed APK...** command in the **Build** menu to guide you through the process.

Comment: Thanks! I found it after reading this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20921456/android-studio-how-to-generate-signed-apk-using-gradle

Answer (score 0):

I had a same problem.

1. Firstly you should go to file that include gradlew.bat with `cd file1\..` .
2. Now you can write `gradlew.bat assembleRelease` .