# how to use assemblerelease in build.gradle file

Tags: android, gradle

i make AAR module file.

i want to use assemblerelease in build.gradlefile

for example

```
task makeAAR{
   // i don't know make assemblerelease
}
```

Comment: Just use `assembleRelease`. What is the final goal what is your issue?

Comment: i want use gradle task

Comment: find this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20921456/android-studio-how-to-generate-signed-apk-using-gradle