# What values I should configure in my github actions secrets in order to sign my apk?

Tags: android, building-github-actions, apk-signing

According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25252900/4706711) I should run te following command in order to build an apk and sign it?

```
./gradlew assembleRelease -Pandroid.injected.signing.store.file=$KEYFILE -Pandroid.injected.signing.store.password=$STORE_PASSWORD -Pandroid.injected.signing.key.alias=$KEY_ALIAS -Pandroid.injected.signing.key.password=$KEY_PASSWORD
```

And using the android studio I made the following key configuration that is used for building the app:

[image: display settings]

The generated files in `/home/pcmagas/Kwdikas/androidKeys/h330s_fu` is contained using the following 2 files:

- h300s_fu
- private_key.pepk

And the action responsible for building and signing the apk is:

```
name: pr
on:
  push:
    branches: [master]

jobs:
  test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout latest code
        uses: actions/checkout@v1
      - name: Set up JDK 8
        uses: actions/setup-java@v2
        with:
          java-version: '8'
          distribution: 'adopt'
      - name: Make gradlew executable
        run: chmod +x ./gradlew
      - name: test
        run: ./gradlew test
      - name: build
        run: ./gradlew buildRelease
      - name: Assemble Release Bundle
        run: ./gradlew assembleRelease
```

Hence the environmental variables:

1. `$KEYFILE`
2. `$STORE_PASSWORD`
3. `$KEY_ALIAS`
4. `$KEY_PASSWORD`

Must be configured with github secrets. But what values should I configure for them? I mean what role has the `h300s_fu` file and the `private_key.pepk` one?