# AAR file is not generating from the lib

Tags: java, android, kotlin, aar

I have a project and the lib module (actually my project is a wrapper on the lib module in order to generate .aar). It's expected to work like this - once I build the project it is supposed to build the lib-module which is supposed to generate (under the hood) `.aar` under the `build->output` folder. So, finally, I can use it, however, the problem is that the `.aar` file is not being generated.

Also, have to mention that actually there are 2 lib modules under the project and the second lib-module `.aar` file generates successfully each time, so obviously it is something wrong with my first lib module.

I have tried to clean, rebuild, invalidate and all of these things, but it doesn't work.

Is there a way to figure out what is a possible issue?

Is there a way to check (eg: with logs) where this `.aar` is generated? Or change the location? Or get any details about the generation process?

Comment: we need more information in order to help you. I recommend creating a separate project as a [mcve] to try to recreate the issue.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice since I am talking about my working project it would be impossible to post the project here :(

Comment: that is why you create a separate project to reproduce the problem as the link I gave earlier describes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally this answer helped me to figure it out - https://stackoverflow.com/a/20927125/5709159, namely this query in terminal - `/gradlew assembleRelease` (or `/gradlew assembleDebug`)