# Gradle produces unsigned release apk

Tags: android, gradle

I have a project with following structure:

```
Root
    \__main_project
    |
    \__modules
       \__
       |  library1
       |   
       \__
          library2
```

I have following config in my gradle:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion '19.0.0'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 19
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile file('/home/home/.signing/test.keystore')
            storePassword 'testtest'
            keyAlias 'testtest'
            keyPassword 'testtest'
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
}
```

to build my project I run following command:

```
./gradlew :main_project:assembleRelease
```

but it only produces main_project-release-unsigned.apk

So my question why it produces unsigned apk when I specified all required configuration.
Thank you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20876069/using-android-studio-how-do-i-get-a-signed-non-debug-and-zip-aligned-apk/20876737#20876737

Comment: I understand that even debug builds are signed with debug.keystore I wonder why it produces apk with the name unsigned? it's strange for me.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The "official" way to configure the build.gradle file as recommended by Google is explained [here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio-build.html#configureSigning).

Basically, you add a "signinConfig", in where you specify the location an password of the keystore.
Then, in the release build type, refer to that signing configuration.

```
...
android {
    ...
    defaultConfig { ... }
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile file("myreleasekey.keystore")
            storePassword "password"
            keyAlias "MyReleaseKey"
            keyPassword "password"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            ...
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
}
...
```

Then build the app with the "assembleRelease" task.

Answer (score 1):

Try `./gradlew assembleRelease`.

Also you'll probably want to augment the buildTypes release section

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        runProguard true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        zipAlign true
    }
}
```

Also see `task askForPasswords` on [How to create a release signed apk file using Gradle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18328730/how-to-create-a-release-signed-apk-file-using-gradle) for how to prompt for the passwords so they aren't stored in this file.