# android-emulator does not start

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-studio

I used to be able to compile and run the project in the emulator of android-studio but I don't know which setting I have changed and now I am able to create the apk by using the assemble comand. However, whenever I press the "Run" button i get this error message: `app-release-unsigned.apk is not signed. Please configure the signing information for the selected flavor using the Project Structure dialog.` I don't care whether the app is signed or not, I just want the app to run in the emulator.

Comment: You have this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25001479/app-release-unsigned-apk-is-not-signed) can you help.

Comment: Change your app **Build option to Debug**. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20876069/using-android-studio-how-do-i-get-a-signed-non-debug-and-zip-aligned-apk) can help